# SonarQube Custom c# rule using roslyn

Tags: c#, .net-core, sonarqube, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am using SonarQube 8.7.1 & visual studio 2019. As per requirement, we are to create a custom c# rule for sonar.

I wrote a C# Roslyn analyzer. It works fine and working as expected. When I try to deploy it under SonarQube using https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube-roslyn-sdk and command is

RoslynSonarQubePluginGenerator /a:CodeAnalyzer

then I got below error

Error:Failed to install package: Updating 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers 1.1.0' to 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers 1.0.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'CodeAnalyzer' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers 1.0.0'.
Check that there are released versions of the package, or specify a pre-release version identifier.

Anyone can help me on this or share the link for the same.

Comment: At a guess: your analyzer references Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers 1.1.0, but SonarQube insists that all analyzers reference Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers 1.0.0? Update the `PackageReference` in your analyzer's csproj to refer to version 1.0.0 of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers, rather than version 1.1.0

Comment: The SonarQube Roslyn SDK (the utility that creates a SonarQube plugin to wrap a Roslyn analyzer) references Roslyn v2.8.2 and contains binding redirects for older versions, so it should work with analyzers built with earlier Roslyn versions.  However, I think the utility is failing at an earlier stage; it's trying to fetch all of the NuGet packages referenced by your analyzer NuGet package before using reflection to create instances of your analyzer types. Check your NuGet package is marked as being a release version. If that isn't the problem, then posting more of the log output would help.

Comment: Thanks duncanp, your answer gave me direction now I am able to resolve my issue, I had to degrade the nuget packages which was compatible to roslyn-sdk utility and it worked